# How to pass the data from a POST into a parameter?

Tags: jquery

I have this code right here:

```
$('#add_club_button').click(function(){
    $('#add_club_button_ajax').show();
    $.post('<?php echo base_url()?>addClub/save',$('#add_club_form').serialize(),function(data){
        if(data == 'OK'){               
            //refresh
            $('#add_club_button_ajax').click(function() {
                      location.reload();
            });             

             $.unblockUI(); //unblock
            $('#add_club_button_ajax').hide();                  

        }
        //c(data);
    });     
});
```

What I want is to store the data I get from `POST` (e.g. id and name) to the database. My problem is that I don't know how to get the data I get from `POST`.

Comment: What web server and language on your web server are you using?

Comment: the data you get from the POST call is in `data` but you can't add it to a DB from javasript. You will need to pass it to a PHP script.

Comment: Are you looking to store data on HTML5 local Database or you want to store it on your server-side database (MySQL or any other type)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to store to a server-side database, you need to use a server side language like PHP to accept your HTML POST variables, prepare them, and process them to the database.

```
<?PHP
mysql_connect('', '', '');
mysql_select_db('') or die("Could not connect to DB");

$variable = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['variable']);

$sql = mysql_query('INSERT INTO "table" ("variable", "") VALUES ("' . $variable . '", ""');
?>
```

Submit your HTML form to a php script containing something like my example above. There is no real need to use jQuery unless you are using it for other reasons than just submitting a form.

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct in guessing that you are using PHP, you would access the data using the $_POST function. I can't tell what you're calling the data that you are passing in though, so I can't write the exact code.

But, let's say you passed in data like 'club-info' then you could access it in a backend PHP script using:

```
$club-info = $_POST['club-info'];
```